# First line fails to load from text file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python I do not understand why my code fails to load the first line. Could someone please take a look?

My code is:

```
f = open("test.txt")
line = f.readline()

joined=[]

while line:
    line=f.readline().split()
    for x in line:
        joined.append(line)

f.close()

print(joined)
```

"test.txt" file looks like this:

```
This is the 1st line !
This is the 2nd line .
This is the 3rd line ?
This is the 4th line
This is the 5th line .
```

I get this (first line is missing, also duplicate entries):

```
[['This', 'is', 'the', '2nd', 'line', '.'], ['This', 'is', 'the', '2nd', 'line', '.'], ['This', 'is', 'the', '2nd', 'line', '.'], ['This', 'is', 'the', '2nd', 'line', '.'], ['This', 'is', 'the', '2nd', 'line', '.'], ['This', 'is', 'the', '2nd', 'line', '.'], ['This', 'is', 'the', '3rd', 'line', '?'], ['This', 'is', 'the', '3rd', 'line', '?'], ['This', 'is', 'the', '3rd', 'line', '?'], ['This', 'is', 'the', '3rd', 'line', '?'], ['This', 'is', 'the', '3rd', 'line', '?'], ['This', 'is', 'the', '3rd', 'line', '?'], ['This', 'is', 'the', '4th', 'line'], ['This', 'is', 'the', '4th', 'line'], ['This', 'is', 'the', '4th', 'line'], ['This', 'is', 'the', '4th', 'line'], ['This', 'is', 'the', '4th', 'line'], ['This', 'is', 'the', '5th', 'line', '.'], ['This', 'is', 'the', '5th', 'line', '.'], ['This', 'is', 'the', '5th', 'line', '.'], ['This', 'is', 'the', '5th', 'line', '.'], ['This', 'is', 'the', '5th', 'line', '.'], ['This', 'is', 'the', '5th', 'line', '.']]
```

But desired output is:

```
[['This', 'is', 'the', '1st', 'line', '!'], ['This', 'is', 'the', '2nd', 'line', '.'],  ['This', 'is', 'the', '3rd', 'line', '?'], ['This', 'is', 'the', '4th', 'line'], ['This', 'is', 'the', '5th', 'line', '.']]
```

Also, is there a way to lowercase all characters in all of the lists?

Comment: Is it just me, but I cannot load the first line of the text file?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension that iterates through lines splitting on space:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    print([x.split() for x in f])

# [['This', 'is', 'the', '1st', 'line', '!'], 
#  ['This', 'is', 'the', '2nd', 'line', '.'],
#  ['This', 'is', 'the', '3rd', 'line', '?'],
#  ['This', 'is', 'the', '4th', 'line'],
#  ['This', 'is', 'the', '5th', 'line', '.']]
```

To make all lower case:

```
print([x.lower().split() for x in f])

# [['this', 'is', 'the', '1st', 'line', '!'],
#  ['this', 'is', 'the', '2nd', 'line', '.'],
#  ['this', 'is', 'the', '3rd', 'line', '?'],
#  ['this', 'is', 'the', '4th', 'line'],
#  ['this', 'is', 'the', '5th', 'line', '.']]
```

---

The reason why you are not getting the first line is because you do `.readline()` outside loop and never used it. You immediately replace that with another `.readline()` in the loop leaving you with lines from second position onwards.

Comment: Oh wow! This works perfectly! Thank you so much. I still don't get why the first line was missing?!

Comment: @Glupan123, Please find the explanation.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You're discarding the value returned by the first `readline()`, which is why the first line of your file is missing in the output. You can iterate over the file object as an iterator instead:

```
joined = []
for line in f:
    joined.append(line.split())
print(joined)
```

Comment: Thank you for this clarification... I did not know that the first "readline()" also removes the first line in the output.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues here. The first is that the first line is not appended to your `joined` list because it is defined and then overwritten at the beginning of the `while` loop on the first iteration before it can be appended to the `joined` list.

The second is that you write:

```
for x in line:
    joined.append(line)
```

Which adds the whole `line` to `joined` for each element in `line`. So the second lines gets appended 6 times because it contains 6 elements. I think you meant to append `x` to `joined`, but that will give you all the words in a single list rather than nested lists as desired. Since each line is already split into a list of individual words, there is no need for this inner loop.

You can write your code more concisely with:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    joined = [line.split() for line in f.readlines()]
```

Result:

```
[['This', 'is', 'the', '1st', 'line', '!'], ['This', 'is', 'the', '2nd', 'line', '.'], ['This', 'is', 'the', '3rd', 'line', '?'], ['This', 'is', 'the', '4th', 'line'], ['This', 'is', 'the', '5th', 'line', '.']]
```

Comment: Thank you Sir for this great clarification. Now the duplicates make sense.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your additional question how to lowercase all characters:

```
str.lower()
```

gives you the lowercase of a string. So to complete the above answer:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
print([x.split().lower() for x in f])
```

This should do it.

Comment: Lists don't have `.lower()`.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion... but I get the following error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'